# Execution stops right after TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a piece of JavaScript code that will allow me to use the arrows to go back and forth in blog posts.

I figured that the easiest and simplest way to do this is to add `id` tags in the anchors that go to the previous-next posts, then have JavaScript read the `href` from the anchor.

I Googled and made it work --I believe I found the answers right here-- but I have this problem- the code doesn't work on the first post. I think this is because there is no `prev` id, and I get a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. This, somehow, stops the execution of code, and I also can't get the `href` for the `prev` id.

How do I fix this?

Here is an HTML demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nextpage;
        var prevpage;

        window.onload=function()
        {
            prevpage = document.getElementById("prev").getAttribute("href");
            nextpage = document.getElementById("next").getAttribute("href");
        }

        document.onkeydown = function(evt)
        {
            evt = evt || window.event;
            switch (evt.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:
                    if (typeof prevpage !== 'undefined') window.location = prevpage;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    if (typeof nextpage !== 'undefined') window.location = nextpage;
                    break;
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li class="previous"><a id="prev" href="http://www.yahoo.com">&laquo; <span>Previous Post</span></a></li>
    <li class="next"><a id="next" href="http://www.google.com"><span>Next Post</span> &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just test if `document.getElementById("prev")` is not `null` then..

Comment: "This, somehow, stops the execution of code" Well of course it stops because there is an error!

Comment: You really should use `<link type="next" href="…">`/`<link type="prev" href="…">` in `<head>` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you must test if [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) returns a DOM element reference or `null`, as trying to access a property of `null` results in an error.

```
window.onload=function()
{
    var prevpage = document.getElementById("prev"),
        nextpage = document.getElementById("next");
    document.onkeydown = function(evt)
    {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode)
        {
            case 37:
                if (prevpage) window.location = prevpage.href;
                break;
            case 39:
                if (nextpage) window.location = nextpage.href;
                break;
        }
    };
};
```

`null` is considered a falsy value, hence it won't enter the `if` block inside of your switch.

Assuming `next`/`prev` are anchors `<a>` you can access their `href` properties directly without using `getAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error if you try to read the attribute of something that is null. So you need to test that it exists before you read it.

```
    window.onload=function()
    {

        var prevElem = document.getElementById("prev");
        var nextElem = document.getElementById("next");

        prevpage = prevElem ? prevElem.href || null;
        nextpage = nextElem ? nextElem.href || null;
    }

    document.onkeydown = function(evt)
    {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        switch (evt.keyCode)
        {
            case 37:
                if (prevpage) window.location = prevpage;
                break;
            case 39:
                if (nextpage) window.location = nextpage;
                break;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

`prevpage = document.getElementById("prev").getAttribute("href");` gives a TypeError, which stops the execution. What I need to do is first check if `document.getElementById("prev")` is null. If it's not, then I can `getAttribute("href")`

I need `getAttribute("href")` because I want to grab the local file --ie `post30.html`, not `http://www.example.com/post30.html`. I forgot to mention that.

This is what the code should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nextpage;
       var prevpage;

       window.onload=function()
        {   
           var temp;

           temp = document.getElementById("prev");  
            if (temp) prevpage = temp.getAttribute("href")

           temp = document.getElementById("next");
            if (temp) nextpage = temp.getAttribute("href")

        }

       document.onkeydown = function(evt)
        {
           evt = evt || window.event;
            switch (evt.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:
                    if (prevpage) window.location = prevpage;
                    break;
                case 39:
                    if (nextpage) window.location = nextpage;
                    break;
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li class="previous"><a id="prev" href="next.html">&laquo; <span>Previous Post</span></a></li>
    <li class="next"><a id="next" href="prev.html"><span>Next Post</span> &raquo;</a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```